# QThread::create running on UI Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I need multi-threading in my application. According to Qt's docs, there are a number of ways to achieve this.

**To briefly overview `QThread`ing methods:**

1. subclass QThread and reimplement run() ([doc](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-starting.html)).
2. Create a object inheriting from `QObject` with `Q_OBJECT` macro (for signals/slots) with `doWork` method, create a `QThread` object, use [QObject::moveToThread(QThread*)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) and call `QThread::start()` ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details), [wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage))
3. use [QThread::create(Function &&f)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#create-1) or `QThread::create(std::function<>)` for lambda syntax.

I have opted to test using the 3rd option. I have also implemented a multithreading library called [QThreading](https://github.com/cybex-dev/QThreading) based on option 2, using a [QWorkerThread](https://github.com/cybex-dev/qthreading/blob/master/QThreading/qworkerthread.cpp) which acts as a controller object with a `QThread` and `QObject` as objects. *This library also gives the same results as shown below.*

---

**Now that the docs are out of the way, the question.**

Using `QThread::create(Function &&f)`, I am testing to see if the QThread runs separately from the UI thread. A **MCVE** example below:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qsrand(0);
    QThread *thread = nullptr;
    auto threadTest = std::function<void ()> ([&]() {

        if(thread->thread() == a.thread()) {
            qDebug() << "UI Thread in use";
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Worker thread in use";
        }

        for (int var = 0; var < INT_MAX; ++var) {
            int r = qrand() % 100;
            thread->thread()->msleep(r);
            qDebug() << "[Worker Thread " << thread->thread()->currentThreadId() << "] " << r;
        }
    });
    thread = QThread::create(threadTest);
    thread->start();

    for (int var = 0; var < INT_MAX; ++var) {
        // sleep thread 0-100ms
        int r = qrand() % 100;
        a.thread()->msleep(r);
        qDebug() << "[UI Thread " << a.thread()->currentThreadId() << "] " << r;
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

**The output is:**

```
UI Thread in use
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  41
[UI Thread  0x10c0 ]  38
[UI Thread  0x10c0 ]  19
[UI Thread  0x10c0 ]  38
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  67
[UI Thread  0x10c0 ]  37
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  34
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  0
[UI Thread  0x10c0 ]  55
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  69
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  24
[UI Thread  0x10c0 ]  97
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  78
[UI Thread  0x10c0 ]  65
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  58
[UI Thread  0x10c0 ]  85
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  62
[UI Thread  0x10c0 ]  50
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  64
[UI Thread  0x10c0 ]  12
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  5
[Worker Thread  0x47e4 ]  45
```

**Things to note**

- UI Thread ID : `0x10c0`
- Worker Thread ID: `0x47e4`

**Where the concern comes in**

> UI Thread in use

What confuses me is the different thread addresses, yet the worker thread is still *equal* to the UI thread.

**That leaves me to 2 explanations:**

1. `QThread::currentThread` always returns the host / main thread (*implausible, makes the function somewhat pointless*)
2. The `QThread *thread` lives inside of the *Main UI Thread* and thus (getting the parent thread) always returns the parent thread i.e. `ParentThread == WorkerThread (ParentThread)`

Do I miss understand how the `QThread` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want to know if it runs in the main thread then you should compare the currentThread with the QCoreApplication thread:

```cpp
if(QCoreApplication::instance()->thread() == QThread::currentThread()) {
    qDebug() << "UI Thread in use";
} else {
    qDebug() << "Worker thread in use";
}
```

2. QThread is not a thread is a thread handler as [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) points out:

> ### Detailed Description
>
> A [`QThread`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) object manages one thread of control within the program.
>   QThreads begin executing in [`run()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run). By default, run() starts the event
>   loop by calling exec() and runs a Qt event loop inside the thread.

In addition, QThread is a QObject that lives in the parent's thread or where it was created if it has no parent as [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity) points out:

> ### Thread Affinity
>
> A QObject instance is said to have a thread affinity, or that it lives
>   in a certain thread. When a QObject receives a queued signal or a
>   posted event, the slot or event handler will run in the thread that
>   the object lives in.
>
> Note: If a QObject has no thread affinity (that is, if thread()
>   returns zero), or if it lives in a thread that has no running event
>   loop, then it cannot receive queued signals or posted events.
>
> By default, a QObject lives in the thread in which it is created. An
>   object's thread affinity can be queried using thread() and changed
>   using moveToThread().
>
> All QObjects must live in the same thread as their parent.
>   Consequently:
>
> - setParent() will fail if the two QObjects involved live in different threads.
> - When a QObject is moved to another thread, all its children will be automatically moved too.
> - moveToThread() will fail if the QObject has a parent.
> - If QObjects are created within QThread::run(), they cannot become children of the QThread object because the QThread does not live in
>     the thread that calls QThread::run().
>
> **Note:** A QObject's member variables do not automatically become
>   its children. The parent-child relationship must be set by either
>   passing a pointer to the child's constructor, or by calling
>   setParent(). Without this step, the object's member variables will
>   remain in the old thread when moveToThread() is called.

In your case "thread" object is a QObject that lives in the main thread since it has no parent and there it was created and that handles another thread.

### Update:

**MWE**

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qsrand(0);
    auto threadTest = std::function<void ()> ([&]() {
        if(QCoreApplication::instance()->thread() == QThread::currentThread()) {
            qDebug() << "UI Thread in use";
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Worker thread in use";
        }

        for (int var = 0; var < INT_MAX; ++var) {
            int r = qrand() % 100;
            QThread::msleep(r);
            qDebug() << "[Worker Thread " << QThread::currentThreadId() << "] " << r;
        }
    });
    QThread *thread = QThread::create(threadTest);
    thread->start();

    int var = 0;
    std::function<void ()> timerTest;
    timerTest = [&](){
        int r = qrand() % 100;
        qDebug() << "[UI Thread " << QThread::currentThreadId() << "] " << r;
        ++var;
        if (var < INT_MAX)
            QTimer::singleShot(r, timerTest);
    };
    int r = qrand() % 100;
    QTimer::singleShot(r, timerTest);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
Worker thread in use
[UI Thread  0x7fc6222993c0 ]  94
[Worker Thread  0x7fc621f62700 ]  71
[UI Thread  0x7fc6222993c0 ]  86
[Worker Thread  0x7fc621f62700 ]  94
[UI Thread  0x7fc6222993c0 ]  37
[Worker Thread  0x7fc621f62700 ]  86
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, don't think I fully understand how QThreads are intended to be used. Per your suggestion,  I changed `if(thread->thread() == a.thread())` to `if(thread->thread() == QCoreApplication::instance()->thread())` but it still reports `UI Thread in use`. How should I use a QThread, to ensure that the code I am running is truly off of the main thread?

Comment: @KGCybeX I have updated my answer with a MWE and it works correctly.

Comment: @KGCybeX On the other hand, your change is incorrect: What is `thread->thread()`? It is the thread where QThread lives and as already stated by QThread lives in the main-thread. You should compare the current thread with the application thread or use: `if(thread == QCoreApplication::instance()->thread())`